# How to use KoinTestRule without getting "A KoinContext is already started"?

Tags: koin

I am trying to use Koin's test rule to start and stop Koin with test modules, however every time I try use this rule or startKoin() I get "A KoinContext is already started". I initially start Koin in the application class, which may have something to do with the issue, but I'm not sure myself how to get around this. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Application:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    startKoin {
        androidContext(this@Application)
        modules(repositoryModule, daoModule, viewModelModule, wrapperModule)
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@get:Rule
val koinTestRule = KoinTestRule.create {
    modules(repositoryTestModule)
}
```

Repository Test Module:

```
val repositoryTestModule = module {
    single<JournalRepository> { FakeJournalRepository() }
}
```

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by creating a custom test application and overriding the onCreate and onTerminate methods, starting and stopping Koin respectively. By not loading any modules in the Application I can load the modules needed by each class.

If there is a better solution I would love to hear it. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a better alternative?